# How to switch into iframe when previous iframe is not closed in selenium webdriver

Tags: html, iframe, selenium-webdriver

My problem is we are using so many iframes in [html](/questions/tagged/html). I am unable to locate the element as element is present in iframe which is again inside the iframe.

I want to locate the element which is inside the top iframe (means 2nd) but i am not able to do so because the previous iframe is not getting closed.

Comment: try switching to first iframe and then to second iframe and then search for element and once done you can move to defaultcontent()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to switch to sibling of the frame that you are in now, we should probably come out of all frames and then switch to that sibling frame from the root. For example consider the below image,
[image: Iframes/Frames]

Switch to Frame 1 from root:

```
 driver.switchTo().frames("Frame 1");
```

Switch to frame 2 which is outside of Frame 1:

```
 //Come to root from Frame 1
 driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

 //Now switch to Frame 2
 driver.switchTo().frames("Frame 2");
```

This is applicable for nested Frames/iFrames also. Hope this helps.

Thanks.